# Send email with out using network credentials

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I want to send email using the SMTP client in C#.  Currently I am using this code:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("receiver");
message.Subject = "";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("sender");
message.Body = "This is a test mail";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(message);
```

But I want to send mail with out using username and password by just providing the sender address.  Is this possible in C#?
Is this possible with any SMTP server(Not google). I mean login to server anonymously and just provide your mail address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Gmail does not allow anonymous senders. Thankfully. 
If it was possible anyone could pretend to send emails from everyone else, rendering gmail as one big spam engine.

Comment: Is this possible with any SMTP server.I mean login to server anonymously and just provide your mail address.

Comment: @Zain, yes of course. If you control the mail server it is indeed very possible.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.that,s mean i have to setup my own smtp server.

Comment: Is this means, i need to programatically log in to smtp server and then i can send mail from xyz@hotmail.co to pqr@yahoo.com . is it your means ? if yes , is any code snipe for that ? so that i can take reference

Comment: In php we use PHP mail() Function that can send mail with out credentials.Is there any equivalent in c#.If no then how PHP mail() Function send email .

Comment: @Zain in c# you just don't set `Credentials`.

Answer (score 2):

The SMTP server in IIS allows this per default if your application is on the same server as IIS.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your server. In your code you are using Gmail and Gmail requires this.

You can set up your own SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

In the end you'll have to send credentials if the server demands them.

You could send the credentials of the current security context if that's what you're looking for. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx.